# How do i filter JSON based on a key, so i only have a list of one type of key for all objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```js
[
  {
    "id":100,
    "account_id":8,
    "name":"Out of Service",
    "default":false,
    "created_at":"2012-02-06T08:51:29.720-06:00",
    "updated_at":"2012-02-06T08:51:29.720-06:00"
  },
  ...
]
```

This is my sample object. I get this from an url fetch app request.
How can i filter this so i can publish a list of only one type of Value.

For example : 
if I want to filter it for Key Id,  i want to get a list that is something like  : 100,101,... So on.

Thanks

Comment: use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Comment: Is this a Java question or a JavaScript question? Those are very different languages, you know.

Comment: java Script. Java was for the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) arrow functions (`=>`) won't work.

Use:

```
function testIt()
{
  var sample = [
    {
      "id":100,
      "account_id":8,
      "name":"Out of Service",
      "default":false,
      "created_at":"2012-02-06T08:51:29.720-06:00",
      "updated_at":"2012-02-06T08:51:29.720-06:00"
    },
    {
      "id":101,
      "account_id":8,
      "name":"Out of Service",
      "default":false,
      "created_at":"2012-02-06T08:51:29.720-06:00",
      "updated_at":"2012-02-06T08:51:29.720-06:00"
    },
  ];  
    var result = sample.map(function(elt) { return elt.id; });
    Logger.log(result); //  [100.0, 101.0]

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `Array.prototype.filter()` you should use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Code:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id":100,
    "account_id":8,
    "name":"Out of Service",
    "default":false,
    "created_at":"2012-02-06T08:51:29.720-06:00",
    "updated_at":"2012-02-06T08:51:29.720-06:00"
  },
  {
    "id":101,
    "account_id":8,
    "name":"Out of Service",
    "default":false,
    "created_at":"2012-02-06T08:51:29.720-06:00",
    "updated_at":"2012-02-06T08:51:29.720-06:00"
  },
]

const result = data.map(obj => obj.id)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use Array.reduce although I'm not sure there are any benefits over Yosvel's map method:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id":100,
    "account_id":8,
    "name":"Out of Service",
    "default":false,
    "created_at":"2012-02-06T08:51:29.720-06:00",
    "updated_at":"2012-02-06T08:51:29.720-06:00"
  },
  {
    "id":102,
    "account_id":8,
    "name":"Out of Service",
    "default":false,
    "created_at":"2012-02-06T08:51:29.720-06:00",
    "updated_at":"2012-02-06T08:51:29.720-06:00"
  },
  {
    "id":105,
    "account_id":8,
    "name":"Out of Service",
    "default":false,
    "created_at":"2012-02-06T08:51:29.720-06:00",
    "updated_at":"2012-02-06T08:51:29.720-06:00"
  },
]

const res = data.reduce(
  (acc, val) => {
    return [...acc, val.id]
  },
  []
)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Do read: https://medium.com/better-programming/the-reduce-spread-anti-pattern-fc0c1c0b23f6

Answer (score 0):

```
const extractFieldArray = (data, key) => data.map(d => d[key]);
```

//`data` is your object, `key` is what you want to extract, like an `id`